# AngularJS - JQuery event handler on a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events

There is the following situation:

I've implemented a chat module with a directive and controller in my AngularJS application. This is used in the **lobby** and for the **game** itself.

Somewhere in the `link()` function of the directive I am using the following code to accept the enter keystroke as an input trigger.

```
$('#msgInput').keypress((e) => {
        if( e.keyCode == 13 ) // Enter
        {
          var chatMsg = {
            message : $('#msgInput').val()
          };

          $('#msgInput').val('');
          scope.chatModel.sendMessage(chatMsg);
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
```

Initially when the page loads for the first time everything works fine - I navigate to the **lobby**, the event handler gets registered and for every input the callback gets executed.

This continues to work until I decide to navigate to the **game** menu.

Once again the directive's link function gets triggered and registers the same event handler as before.

[image]

From this point any `keypress()` to the input box isn't handled by the event handler anymore.

As soon as I reload the page (f5) either in the lobby or game - everything goes back to normal and works fine and stops once again when I navigate back to the other menu (lobby or menu).

**Edit:** When I navigate back to the menu where I came from, the **keypress()** also stopped working for this menu (now for the lobby & game). Only a reload helps.

What am I missing? The event handler apparently gets registered but just doesn't trigger after an initial navigation in either menu.

Comment: why not use ng-keypress="myHandler($event) instead of ugly jquery by-id binding inside the linking function ? Seeing that you're not even calling $digest in your jQuery handler, that would probably make the whole thing works

Comment: works perfectly fine with ng-keypress and totally forgot about the $digest part ...

Comment: The best approach when not forced to do otherwise is to use base angular directives for this kind of stuff :)

Comment: yes, definitely agree with that - totally forgot about the part that angular also implements its own events ..